# PHP Script Undefined Property and Invalid Argument Errors

Tags: php

I am trying to run this PHP file and I keep getting errors like

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$games
```

and

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

This is a picture of the error http://imageshack.us/a/img845/6270/34356212.jpg and below is the script I am running minus my Steam API key.

```
<?php
$api_key = '........';      //Steam API Key, Required to work
$lines = file('parse1.txt');                        //reads in the file with the list of user numbers
$game_id = 550;                                     //Steam Game ID, 440 is TF2

foreach ($lines as $usernumber) {                    //loops line by line
$link = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=' . $api_key . '&steamid=' . $usernumber . '&format=json';
$json = file_get_contents($link);                   //Reads link (this ^)
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->response->games as $game) { 
    if ($game->appid == $game_id) {
        $playtime = $game->playtime_forever;
        if (($playtime < 5400) && ($playtime > 1)) {
        //echo 'Playtime for ', $usernumber, ' is ' . $playtime."<br>";
                echo $usernumber."<br>";        
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Parse.txt contains steam ID's eg (76561197987683795, 76561198063283029)
I assume it has something to do with nested IF commands, but I have no idea what I am missing, any help would be huge! Thanks

Comment: Can you post the response json?

Comment: The screenshot is the response as far as I know, unless there is something else I should post?

Comment: JSON is not decoded properly to the object class you would like to use. It contains some different data or invalid data.

Comment: Can you post the value of `$json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` object in your json does not contain a `games` array.

You'll want to add some more defense to your code to handle situations where external data does not meet expectations:

```
if (!empty($data->response->games)) {
    foreach ($data->response->games as $game) { 
        if ($game->appid == $game_id) {
            $playtime = $game->playtime_forever;
            if (($playtime < 5400) && ($playtime > 1)) {
            //echo 'Playtime for ', $usernumber, ' is ' . $playtime."<br>";
                    echo $usernumber."<br>";        
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Games missing!';
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Because the script actually works it just errors all over the place while working, so I assume nothing is missing, something is just written wrongly

Comment: You win the badass award! It works like a charm and you are fast as superman! Thanks a ton man! As soon as it will let me, I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$data->response->games
```

this key doesn't seem to exist in your JSON response. Try to debug it yourself by writing after the `json_decode` call: `var_dump($data->response);`. This should help you to see what's going wrong here.